# list trottling powershell script

Tags: powershell

currently my list has threshold value of 5000, I want to increase threashold and disable trottling. I can increase list threshold value from central admin but that would decrease performance of application. Can anyone provide me powershell script to increase threashold for a particular list only.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable list throttling at specific list SharePoint 2010 using SharePoint Manager or PowerShell script, but you can't increase the threshold for specific list.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://myserver
$list = $web.Lists["MyCustomList"]
$list.EnableThrottling = $false
```

**Remember**: Disabling it will cause performance problems as suggested by links provided by Marius!

Update: added some links for further reading

[MSDN: Handling Large Folders and Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557257.aspx)

[TechNet Designing large lists and maximizing list performance](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc262813%28office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: *error:*The property 'EnableThrottling' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge the actual List Threshold is only available at the Web Application level (best explanation here http://nickhobbs.wordpress.com/2013/06/13/sharepoint-2010-list-view-threshold-explained/), but not List level (you can though Exempt your list from being throttled using this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.enablethrottling(office.14).aspx - requires Farm Addministrator to set this property - also find explanation of these options here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798465.aspx)!

You can also programatically override this in your Query or use best practices and design your query to use Content Iterator (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557257(v=office.14).aspx and example http://prasannabj.blogspot.ch/2013/04/handling-large-list-with-content.html)